# Simulating GNU Screen's shelltitle in tmux

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I'm trying to simulate GNU Screen's `shelltitle` feature in tmux.  I have the
following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == screen* ]]; then
    SCREEN_ESC='\[\ek\e\\\]'
else
    SCREEN_ESC=''
fi

PS1="\n\w ${SCREEN_ESC}$ "
```

and the following in my `~/.screenrc`:

```
shelltitle        "$ |bash"
```

Setting `shelltitle` makes GNU Screen search for a newline in the shell and
strip away all the characters from `$PS1` upto the escape character, and replace
it with the first word found after that.  This is more clearly explained in the
[man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/screen.1.html#contenttoc11):

> Here's how it works:  you must modify your shell prompt to output a null
>   title-escape-sequence (<esc>k<esc>) as  a  part of  your prompt.  The last
>   part of your prompt must be the same as the string you specified for the
>   search portion of the title.  Once this is set up, screen will use the
>   title-escape-sequence to clear the previous command name and  get  ready for
>   the  next command.  Then, when a newline is received from the shell, a search
>   is made for the end of the prompt.  If found, it will grab the first word
>   after the matched string and use it as the command name.  If the command  name
>   begins with  either  '!', '%', or '^' screen will use the first word on the
>   following line (if found) in preference to the just- found name.

This is different from tmux's `set-option -g set-titles on` which only captures
the process name.  So a Python script `script.py` would be titled as `script.py`
in Screen (which is the way I want it) whereas, it would be titled as `python`
in tmux (which I don't want.)

I know that one can [rename tmux windows](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/automatic-tmux-titles/) by:

```
printf '\033kWINDOW_NAME\033\\'
```

So I was wondering if there is some way I can alternatively let tmux know that
I've entered a new command.  If there is some way I can get the last command
entered, I could use Bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND` to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Alas, after years, a solution! I also had the same problem with tmux and missed screen's behaviour. In a nutshell:

Add this to `.bashrc`

```
if [ -v "TMUX" ]; then
    PS0='$(printf "\033k%s\033" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'
    PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\033kBASH\033\\'"
```

and this on `tmux.conf`

```
set -g allow-rename on
```

For an explanation of `bashrc`, `PS0` line have a look at this:
[Pass every command executed in the bash shell to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105308/pass-every-command-executed-in-the-bash-shell-to-a-variable/65107604#65107604)

For `PROMPT_COMMAND` I've used `BASH` as a label when returning to bash, you can put whatever you like (ie `>_`). Or you can omit `PROMPT_COMMAND` and leave the last command executed to be seen on the label.